# An exception is not thrown using throw command

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am coding a method that return an instance of FragmentManager as shown in the code belwo.
the prblem is, I want to throw an exception if the context passed to the method is null and then terminate the App.

what happens is, when I pass null to the method mentioned below, the App closes but the message in the NullPointerException which is :

```
getFragmentManagerInstance: Context reference is null
```

is not displayed

please let me know how to throw an exception and terminate the App correctly.

**libs**:

```
public static FragmentManager getFragmentManagerInstance(Activity activity) throws Exception {

    try {
        if (activity != null) {
            return activity.getFragmentManager();
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException("getFragmentManagerInstance: Context reference is null");
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother throwing the exception? Why not just terminate directly?

Comment: @AndyTurner i thought it is a good way  show an exception before terminate the App..but If i would nt have thrown an eception and just terminate the App, how can I print a log message to the user then?

Comment: Don't catch it.  Let it propagate up.

Comment: @user2121 the best way to show an exception would be `new WhateverExceptionType().printStackTrace()`, or similar. You can create exceptions without throwing them.

Comment: @user2121 You should be logging the exception within the catch block, before `System.exit()`, exception stack traces don't get printed by magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "getFragmentManagerInstance: Context reference is null" is being stored in e. **You need to print it to make it display on the screen.**

In the catch block, add a print statement before System.exit(1)

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the try block. Simply typing

```java
    if (activity != null) {
        return activity.getFragmentManager();
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("getFragmentManagerInstance: Context reference is null");
    }
```

will do what you want, since `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception.

Comment: If the goal is to terminate the application if the value is null, this *isn't* what OP wants. This NPE could be caught at a higher layer. (Not that I agree this is what OP *should* want).

Answer (score 0):

> is not displayed

Sure, that's because you're swallowing the exception:

```
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.exit(1);
    return null;
}
```

The message is carried in `e`, and you're not using that in the `catch` block.

---

Note that it is almost *never* the right thing to do to catch a `NullPointerException`. In this case, you can simply print the message and terminate the app directly:

```
if (thing == null) {
  System.err.println("It's null!");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `e.printStackTrace()`

before `System.exit(1)`

and it will print as you wished

Answer (score 0):

The message is not being displayed because you haven't written any code to print it. If you want to display message, add `e.printStackTrace();` before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print some information you need to provide them to an output stream such as `System.out` or `System.err`.

By default if you call `ex.printstacktrace()` it will print the exception within in System.err.

You can also use `ex.printstacktrace(System.out)` to choose where you send the information such as a file, the console or any output.

Also your application will immediately stop after the System.exit so your line of code need to be before the exit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suprised this hasn't been stated yet, change your `catch` block to

```
} catch(NullPointerException e){
    System.err.print(e.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
    return null;
}
```

And if you want to print a message to the user, consider using a `Toast` instead of Exception message.